# Error en mi consulta de SQL con PHP

Tags: php, sql

Tengo un error en la linea numero 5 de mi consulta, pero no logre entender bien cual es el error. Esto es lo que me lanza: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es mi código:**

```
<?php

// Cantidad de usuarios registrados
$stmt = $conexion->query("SELECT id_usuario, COUNT(id_usuario) AS cantidad FROM users WHERE email = $email");
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // cantidad de usuarios registrados
    $usuarioRegistrados = $row['cantidad'];

}

?>
```

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\bomgos\backend\analytics.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bomgos\analytics.php(8): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\bomgos\backend\analytics.php on line 5

Seria de gran importancia su ayuda, un cordial saludo.

Comment: Quita la linea `//$stmt->execute();`

Comment: `$stmt` evalúa a true/false si la query fue satisfactoria/o no y aplicar un `execute()` sobre un bool da ese error

Comment: De la manera que me explica @BetaM, ya no me da error, pero ahora ocurre un problema y es que no me funciona la consulta ni reconoce la variable para sacar la cantidad de usuarios registrados de la plataforma

Comment: `<?php

// Cantidad de usuarios registrados
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT id_usuario, COUNT(id_usuario) AS cantidadUser FROM users WHERE email = $email");
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // cantidad de usuarios registrados
    $cantidadUser = $row['cantidadUser'];

}

?>`  **Este es el error que me sale** 
Notice: Undefined variable: cantidadUser in C:\xampp\htdocs\bomgos\backend\analytics.php on line 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya logre solucionar mi error.
Me salia ese error porque me estaba olvidando que al hacer la comparación en la consulta no le estaba pasando las comillas simple y **PHP** interpretaba que la variable *$email* era un **INT** y no un **String**.

Por otra parte mi código estaba mal escrito, ya que lo que yo quiero es sacar la cantidad de usuarios que hay registrado en la plataforma para hacer eso la consulta **SQL** no debe de tener condiciones. Muchas gracias a todas las personas que mostraron interés en ayudarme a solucionar mi error

**Aquí esta el código ya resuelto sin errores y funcionando:**

```
<?php

// Cantidad de usuarios registrados
$stmt = $conexion->query("SELECT id_usuario, COUNT(id_usuario) AS cantidad FROM users");
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // cantidad de usuarios registrados
    $usuarioRegistrados = $row['cantidad'];

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu SQL: `"SELECT id_usuario, COUNT(id_usuario) AS cantidad FROM users WHERE email = $email"`

Tu SQL con GROUP BY: `"SELECT id_usuario, COUNT(id_usuario) AS cantidad FROM users WHERE email = $email GROUP BY id_usuario"`

Le hace falta el `GROUP BY id_usuario`. Cuando es [`COUNT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) solo no es necesario; más sin embargo como en el caso que muestra quieres obtener el conteo por cada `id_usuario` tu [`COUNT` requiere el `GROUP BY`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp). Desde luego si por el email solo hay un id_usuario (si fuera el caso) con que quites el `ìd_usuario` debe ser suficiente.